# Do you need a separate [DllImport(...)] for each function in C# when importing from a C++ DLL?

Tags: c#, c++, dll, dllimport

I am experimenting with DLLs to try and design a wrapper around a C++ library that allows class objects to be used in C# applications.

I am using System.Runtime.InteropServices to import functions one by one into my C# program as follows:

Program.cs:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        [DllImport(@"..\..\..\Project1\x64\Debug\Project1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int AddNumbers(int a, int b);
        [DllImport(@"..\..\..\Project1\x64\Debug\Project1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int SubtractNum(int a, int b);

        [DllImport(@"..\..\..\Project1\x64\Debug\Project1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern IntPtr Foo_Create(int a, int b);
        public static extern int Foo_getFoo(IntPtr pFoo);
        [DllImport(@"..\..\..\Project1\x64\Debug\Project1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int Foo_addBar(IntPtr pFoo, int a);
        [DllImport(@"..\..\..\Project1\x64\Debug\Project1.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
        public static extern int Foo_Delete(IntPtr pFoo);

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int output = AddNumbers(5, 11);
            int output2 = SubtractNum(11, 5);
            Console.WriteLine($"Output: {output} - {output2}");

            IntPtr foo = Foo_Create(6, 6);
            Console.WriteLine($"Expect 6, got: {Foo_getFoo(foo)}");
            Console.WriteLine($"Expected 10, got: {Foo_addBar(foo, 4)}");
            Foo_Delete(foo);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a more concise way to import these functions than having to have a separate DllImport() for each one? When I remove one, I see the warning "Method, operator, or accessor 'method' is marked external and has no attributes on it. Consider adding a DllImport attribute to specify the external implementation." so I assume it is necessary.

For reference the c++ file that I am compiling into a DLL is as follows:

```
#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport )

extern "C" {
    DllExport int AddNumbers(int a, int b) {
        return a + b;
    }
    DllExport int SubtractNum(int a, int b) {
        return a - b;
    }
}

class DllExport Foo {
    public:
        Foo(int a, int b) {
            foo = a;
            bar = b;
        }
        int getFoo() { return foo; };
        int addBar(int a) { return private_method(a); };
    private:
        int private_method(int a) { return a + bar; };
        int foo;
        int bar;
};

// Wrapper functions to provide access to class methods that should be available to client
extern "C" DllExport Foo * Foo_Create(int a, int b) { return new Foo(a, b); }
extern "C" DllExport int Foo_getFoo(Foo * pFoo) { return pFoo->getFoo(); }
extern "C" DllExport int Foo_addBar(Foo * pFoo, int a) { return pFoo->addBar(a); }
extern "C" DllExport void Foo_Delete(Foo * pFoo) { delete pFoo; }
```

Comment: Side point: You need to be careful with functions like `extern "C" DllExport Foo * Foo_Create(int a, int b) { return new Foo(a, b); }` You need to make sure the calling code always disposes/deletes the memory by using `Foo_Delete`

Comment: I'm new to C#, mostly a C programmer so I am use to having to do this automatically. I assume then it is not good practice to assume C# users to always use Delete? I'm sure there is some way I could write a wrapper in C# to provide a way to interface with these functions in a class structure that would automatically call Foo_Delete when the object goes out of scope

Comment: Generally it's recommended to allow C# to pass in a pre-sasigned buffer (and size of buffer if necessary) for you to send data back. For example you could make such a parameter like this in C# `[Out] Foo pFoo` and the marshaller will automatically copy the data back into the object.

Answer (score 0):

If your library has functions like this then yes, you have to DllImport each separately.

If you control the DLL, you could add a function that returns a structure containing function pointers (or pointer to such a structure) and then import just that function. That is basically what COM interop does, simply hiding where the structure comes from.

Comment: Aahh I hadn't thought of that, thank you